# A Question about "full marks"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-usage

Is that correct to say that I have completed several courses with full marks?

I want to say that I have finished some courses that I obtained full marks in exams.

Does it make sense to use the phrase "finish courses with full marks"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say that.

> full marks
>
> 1. plural noun
>
> If you get full marks in a test or exam, you get everything right and
>   gain the maximum number of marks.

[Full marks](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/full-marks)